# Roman Numerals converter its different from others

Tags: java, roman-numerals

I keep getting this error code:

----jGRASP exec: javac -g RomanNumerals.java

RomanNumerals.java:56: unreachable statement

defult:

1 error

----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RomanNumerals
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int input;

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
      input = keyboard.nextInt();

      switch (input)
      {
         case 1:
            System.out.println("I");
            break;
         case 2:
            System.out.println("II");
            break;
         case 3:
            System.out.println("III");
            break;
         case 4:
            System.out.println("IV");
            break;
         case 5:
            System.out.println("V");
            break;
         case 6:
            System.out.println("VI");
            break;
         case 7:
            System.out.println("VII");
            break;
         case 8:
            System.out.println("VIII");
            break;
         case 9:
            System.out.println("IX");
            break;
         case 10:
            System.out.println("X");
            break;
         defult:
            System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 10. ");
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: um... "defult"?  -- please check your spelling!

Answer (score 2):

you have typed 'defult:', but it should be ' default:'

try

```
default:
            System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 10. ");
```

Comment: OMG really -.-; thanks so much for your help upog!